# MongoDB lookup array of objects by field and retain other fields in result

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to figure out how to do a lookup on an array of objects by a specific field, while retaining other fields that are at the same level of the looked up field.

My `processes` collection is as follows:

```
{
    _id: 'p1',
    steps: [
        {
            _id: 'ps1',
            step: 's1',
            time: 10
        },
        {
            _id: 'ps2',
            step: 's2',
            time: 15
        }
    ]
}
```

The `steps` collection looks like (for the document with `_id: s1`):

```
{
    _id: 's1',
    name: 'step 1'
}
```

My aggregation:

```
processes.aggregate([
    {
        // match stage or whatever prior stage
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
             from: 'steps',
             localField: 'steps.step',
             foreignField: '_id',
             as: 'steps'
        }
    }
])
```

This works, but basically erases the `steps._id` and `steps.time` fields that were at the same level of the looked up field (`steps.step`), as seen in the output:

```
{
    _id: 'p1',
    steps: [
        {
            _id: 's1',
            name: 'step 1'
        },
        {
            _id: 's2',
            name: 'step 2'
        }
    ]
}
```

While the expected output would be:

```
{
    _id: 'p1',
    steps: [
        {
            _id: 'ps1',
            time: 10,
            stepId: 's1',
            name: 'step 1',
        },
        {
            _id: 'ps2',
            time: 15,
            stepId: 's2',
            name: 'step 2',
        }
    ]
}
```

***Note***: the `_id` field in the expected output is not very important, and can contain the _id of the `step` document, avoiding to have a separate `stepId` field.

### EDIT

Additional question moved here: [MongoDB lookup array of objects by field (join conditions and uncorrelated sub-queries)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62327702/mongodb-lookup-array-of-objects-by-field-join-conditions-and-uncorrelated-sub-q)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of research, I could find the way to accomplish what I meant in the question.

The main idea is to merge two arrays of objects together.

```
processes.aggregate([
    {
        // match stage or whatever prior stage
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
             from: 'steps',
             localField: 'steps.step',
             foreignField: '_id',
             as: 'steps2'
        },
        {
            $addFields: {
              stages: {
                $map: {
                  input: '$steps',
                    in: {
                      $mergeObjects: [
                        '$$this',
                        {
                          $arrayElemAt: [
                            '$steps2',
                            {
                              $indexOfArray: ['$steps2._id', '$$this.step'],
                            },
                          ],
                        },
                      ],
                    },
                  },
                },
              },
        }
    }
])
```