# MongoDB lookup array of objects by field (join conditions and uncorrelated sub-queries)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I don't understand what I'm missing with the aggregation lookup using [join conditions and uncorrelated sub-queries](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-uncorrelated-sub-queries).

`processes` collection:

```
{
    _id: 'p1',
    steps: [
        {
            _id: 'ps1',
            step: 's1',
            time: 10
        },
        {
            _id: 'ps2',
            step: 's2',
            time: 15
        }
    ]
}
```

`steps` collection (for the document with `_id: s1`):

```
{
    _id: 's1',
    name: 'step 1'
}
```

Working aggregation (standard one, **without** join conditions and uncorrelated sub-queries):

```
processes.aggregate([
    {
        // match stage or whatever prior stage
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
             from: 'steps',
             localField: 'steps.step',
             foreignField: '_id',
             as: 'steps'
        }
    }
])
```

Output:

```
{
    _id: 'p1',
    steps: [
        {
            _id: 's1',
            name: 'step 1'
        },
        {
            _id: 's2',
            name: 'step 2'
        }
    ]
}
```

Not working aggregation:

```
processes.aggregate([
    {
        // match stage or whatever prior stage
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'steps',
            let: { stepId: '$steps.step' }, // I think the problem is here
            pipeline: [
                {
                    $match: {
                        $expr: { $eq: ['$_id', '$$stepId'] },
                    },
                },
                {
                    // Additional stages here
                }
            ],
            as: 'steps',
        },
    }
])
```

Output:

```
{
    _id: 'p1',
    steps: []
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`steps.step` evaluates to an array of strings in this case `["s1", "s2"]`. The regular `$lookup` supports such comparison and does `$in` behind the scenes.

In your second example you're using `$expr` so you need to use expression language hence you have to use [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/) operator:

```
$expr: { $in: ['$_id', '$$stepId'] }
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9Lprzoj_xcH)