# Mongodb 2 collection with collection array

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I have two collections, Collection B has a general setting, the second collections has an ID stored in the field from B in the field, it needs to join them see the result.

Collection A

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "602ece156f898fc3a6da0440"
},
"name": "Atlas Adventures 2021",
"setup": [{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "602ece156f898fc3a6da0441"
    },
    "typ": {
        "$oid": "602eca46ad462fc07836d5e2"
    },
    "cena": 100,
    "kapacita": 100
}, {
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "602ece156f898fc3a6da0442"
    },
    "typ": {
        "$oid": "602eca59ad462fc07836d5e3"
    },
    "cena": 50,
    "kapacita": 200
}],
```

}

Collection B

```
{
  {
      "_id": {
          "$oid": "602eca46ad462fc07836d5e2"
      },
      "nazev": "12 - 14 let - bez rozlišení\t",
      "zkratka": "A",
      "__v": 0,
      "slozeniMaximum": 2,
      "slozeniMinimum": 2,
  },
  {
      "_id": {
          "$oid": "602eca59ad462fc07836d5e3"
      },
      "zkratka": "B",
      "nazev": "15-17 let",
      "__v": 0,
      "slozeniMaximum": 2,
      "slozeniMinimum": 2,
  }
}
```

Need

```
{
  {
      "_id": {
          "$oid": "602eca46ad462fc07836d5e2"
      },
      "nazev": "12 - 14 let - bez rozlišení\t",
      "zkratka": "A",
      "slozeniMaximum": 2,
      "slozeniMinimum": 2,
      "cena": 50,
      "kapacita": 200,
  },
  {
      "_id": {
          "$oid": "602eca59ad462fc07836d5e3"
      },
      "zkratka": "B",
      "nazev": "15-17 let",
      "slozeniMaximum": 2,
      "slozeniMinimum": 2,
      "cena": 50,
      kapacita": 200,
  }
}
```

But I do not know how.
I've tried aggregation and pipeline, but I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: have you checked lookup: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/ ?

Comment: It will be slightly different, https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/. 
But if read : write ratio permits, consider denormalizing.

Answer (score 0):

According to this example [agreggation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62327702/mongodb-lookup-array-of-objects-by-field-join-conditions-and-uncorrelated-sub-q), I created the following aggregation. There may be a problem with ObjectId.

```
CollectionB.aggregate([{
  $lookup: {
    from: 'CollectionA',
    let: { katId: '$_id' },
    pipeline: [
      {
        $match: {
          $expr: { $in: ['$setup.typ', '$$katId'] },
        },
      }
    ],
    as: 'kategorie',
  }
}
```

I still end in failure